# How can we prove that there is a finite set for every infinite set, in an infinite list of infinite sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given an infinite list of infinite sets of natural numbers (each set is sorted by size of the elements), I would like to find a proof that says we can always find a unique finite set of x natural numbers that correspond to the first x natural numbers in each infinite set (see example below).

I think that a proof is possible since we always have an infinite number of digits to choose from, but we will always need only a finite number of digits for our finite set.

I just don't know how to write such a proof, any help in how to approach this would be appreciated. Or, if this is not possible, how could we prove the opposite.

> $1 \to \{ \color{red}{1} ,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 \dots \} \mapsto \{ \color{red}{1} \}$
>
> $2 \to \{ \color{red}{2} ,4,6,8,10,12,14 \dots \} \mapsto \{ \color{red}{2} \}$
>
> $3 \to \{ \color{red}{1,3} ,5,7,9,11,13,15 \dots \} \mapsto \{ \color{red}{1,3} \}$
>
> $4 \to \{ \color{red}{1,2} ,3,7,9,19,27,31 \dots \} \mapsto \{ \color{red}{1,2} \}$
>
> $5 \to \{ \color{red}{1,2,3} ,4,21,22,25,32 \dots \} \mapsto \{ \color{red}{1,2,3} \}$
>
> $6 \to \{ \color{red}{2,3} ,4,6,7,8,21,55,58 \dots \} \mapsto \{ \color{red}{2,3} \}$
>
> $7 \to \{ \color{red}{2,3,4} ,6,7,8,9,21,55,58 \dots \} \mapsto \{ \color{red}{2,3,4} \}$
>
> $\dots$

Comment: Your comment "(sorted by size)" looks innocent, but in fact it is impossible to make sense of! Given two infinite sets of natural numbers, how do you decide which is bigger?

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether I understand you correctly. You want to show that you can pick the smallest $n$ natural numbers from each of your finite sets? If you have infinitely many (infinite) sets, this looks like the axiom of choice together with the fact that the natural numbers are ordered.

Comment: @TonK the elements are sorted, not the sets, the sets are in random or arbitrary order.

Comment: Do you mean [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)? But in fact the ordering of the list is irrelevant; what matters is the size of your "infinite list".

Comment: @TonyK: He's not talking about ordering the list, so talking about lexicographic order is irrelevant. He's just saying "for each of the subsets of $\mathbb N$ I want the three elements of the subset that come first if we arrange the elements of the subset in increasing order".

Comment: @IvanHieno: How do you decide that you want, say, one element from set number $2$ but three elements from set number $5$? There doesn't seem to be a clear rule for how many elements you're taking.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Where did the number three come from? One of us has gravely misunderstood the question, and I am inclined to stand by my interpretation.

Comment: @Henning Makholm you take enough elements to make a unique set to pair with the infinite set in question.

Comment: @TonyK: It looks like I had slightly misread the question. But it is not clear to me what the interpretation you "stand by" even is. Could you clarify what it is you think the question means?

Comment: @IvanHieno: If you decide once and for all to take the $n$ smallest elements of set number $n$, then the results you get are (trivially) guaranteed to be distinct.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I think the OP wants to know whether their idea works: given a sequence $(S_n)$ of infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$, we can index them using finite subsets, by taking the $n$th index set to be the shortest initial segment of $S_n$ that has not yet occurred as an index set. OP, if you are reading this: your idea does work! (But you might have stated it more carefully.)

Comment: @HenningMakholm is right, since the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ chosen set and the $m^{\textrm{th}}$ chosen set have a  different number of elements if $n\neq m$. I suppose OP is proposing to choose the "most efficient" set (least size but still unique) at each stage. I would prefer HenningMakholm's approach since the size of the chosen set is actually known in his scheme. But out of context, who can tell which is the "best" way? At any rate, this is simpler IMHO.

Comment: @TonyK: Ok, that matches what I think I get from their last comment.

Comment: WARNING! Ivan Hieno [says this about himself](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/369757/ivan-hieno): "
Of course, I am a mathematical crank, not because Cantor was wrong, but he was meaningless. All infinite sets are infinite, it makes no sense to say that some infinite sets are more infinite than other infinite sets." So this question comes with an agenda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking TonyK's interpretation of the question:

> I think the OP wants to know whether their idea works: given a sequence $(S_n)$ of infinite subsets of $N$, we can index them using finite subsets, by taking the $n$th index set to be the shortest initial segment of $S_n$ that has not yet occurred as an index set.

Yes, this does work.

The fact that makes it work is that at each step in the construction there are infinitely many different finite prefixes of $S_n$ to choose from, but only finitely many of these can have been used for earlier sets yet. So there is always *some* unused prefix to choose, and therefore a *shortest* unused prefix.

The above paragraph would count as a full proof in everyday mathematics.

If you want to reduce it all the way down to the nuts and bolts of axiomatic set theory, you'd be looking for a proof that the above recursive description actually defines a function with domain $\mathbb N$. For this you should look for an appropriate variant of the [recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem).

Comment: I think we have achieved a consensus :-)

Answer (score 2):

> **Well-ordering principle:** Every non-empty set of natural numbers contains a (unique) least element.

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ be an infinite set of natural numbers. Then for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a unique finite set $F_n\subseteq X$ containing the $n$ least elements of $X$.

Proof: By induction on $n$. For the basis case $n=1$, the well-ordering principle guarantees a least element $x\in X$. Take $F_1=\{x\}$ and we are done.

For the inductive step, suppose we have a finite set $F_n$ containing the $n$ least elements of $X$, and we wish to form a new finite set $F_{n+1}$ containing the $n+1$ least elements. Consider the set $X\setminus F_n$, the elements of $X$ which are not in $F_n$. Since $X$ is infinite and $F_n$ is finite, $X\setminus F_n$ must be infinite, thus it is non-empty. By the well-ordering principle, $X\setminus F_n$ must contain a least element, call it $x$. Let $F_{n+1}=F_n\cup\{x\}$, so that $F_{n+1}$ is the set of $n+1$ least elements of $X$, completing the proof.

Comments: The proof should be intuitive. To form the finite set, keep selecting the least element from the infinite set, guaranteed by well-ordering principle, subtract that element, and repeat until you have a set of the proper size.

Comment: Put more simply: let $x_n$ be the $n$th smallest element of $S$. Invoking well-ordering here is overkill.

Comment: It seems that you have not addressed the OP's question at all.

Comment: @Tony: To be fair, how do you even know that there is an $n$th smallest element? This is exactly the well-ordering principle. In contrast, what would be the $n$th smallest element of $\Bbb Z$? There is no such thing, because there is no smallest element to begin with, because $\Bbb Z$ is not well-ordered.

Comment: OP seeks a  "proof that says we can always find a unique finite set of $x$ natural numbers that correspond to the first $x$ natural numbers in each infinite set", this is exactly what was shown

Comment: @M.Nestor: That's what the OP _says_ they want. But I can't believe that it's what they really want. Can you?